# how to call console->command->handle function inside controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I Want to call this handle function inside a controller

```
class SendPackageInfoSms extends Command 
{
   public function handle($mobile, $msg) 
   {
       $notify = new Notification;
       $notify->PackageSMS($mobile, $msg);
   }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. This used for task scheduling(CRON). The only thing you can do is call scheduler

Comment: I will suggest you one way by that you ca  archive your requirement,
Create one controller function and use them in the handler function. so all your code "$notify = new Notification; $notify->PackageSMS($mobile, $msg);"
Will be part of one controller and then you can use the same controller function other controller function.

Comment: This is a good example of why you shouldn't put any business logic directly in controllers or commands. The business logic should be put in Services, which you then can use from where ever you want.

Comment: Please can you show how you currently execute the command i.e. if it's from the cli what is the command you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Laravel commands directly from controller with

```
Artisan::call('command:signature', [your_parameters_go_here]);
```

> remember to include Artisan facade on top of your file

Calling the command will automatically execute your handle function.

Answer (score -2):

No Way !! You can execute command form controller but you cann't call this function form controller !!

Comment: Route::get('/foo', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
        'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
    ]);

    //
});

#Programmatically Executing Commands
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan